# Change the content of a div using Jquery (Jquery dialog with parameters)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm working on an ASP.NET website (MVC3 but not really important for my question)

I have some links on my page when the user clicks a link I want to open a Jquery Modal Dialog:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

for each link I want a different dialog to show.

As i understood I have to specify the content of the dialog in a `<div>` on my page. For example:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Here we put the content of the dialog</p>
</div>
```

Links are generated dynamically and I do not want to create a div for each link.
also the content of the dialog depends on parameters send by the link

I will try to explain what I want.

What I want is to do the following if possible:

I have one div

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
</div>
```

when the user clicks on link1 a function is called `ShowDialog(FirstName1, LastName1)`

that function will add the parameters as string to the `div` "dialog" and open the dialog.

when the user clicks on link2 the 'div' "dialog" is cleared and new content are filled by the function `ShowDialog(FirstName2, LastName2)`and the dialog is opened.

all should be done is Jquery or Javascript.

I hope I was clear. if more info is needed please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified where you will be retrieveing the `firstname` and `surname` values from, so I've assigned them to `data-*` attributes of the link, like this:

```
<a href="#" data-firstname="Foo" data-surname="Bar">Click me</a>
```

```javascript
$("#dialog").dialog({ /* settings */ });

$("#link2").click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var fn = $el.data("firstname");
    var sn = $el.data("surname");
    ShowDialog(fn, sn);
});

function ShowDialog(firstname, surname) {
    // Here you can do whatever is required to the dialog, create elements, change text, go nuts.
    $("p", "#dialog").text("Hello " + firstname + " " + surname); 

    // Show the dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
}
```